# How should we handle questions that ask to do the impossible because of naivete (or lack of RTFM)

Tags: discussion

This is not a duplicate of [Should "Did not do the research" questions be answered or penalised?](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/799/should-did-not-do-the-research-questions-be-answered-or-penalised) . It doesn't address the situation where the question is absurd and cannot be answered simply because the request is unreasonable.

I'd like to clarify I am not talking about asking how to work around a limitation.

Sometimes I see questions that not only deserve a "RTFM" but also simply could not be answered because the request contradicts the information provided by the user.

For instance, I want to accomplish X with tool Y that states specifically it was not in any way designed to support the specified feature.

This does not fall under "too broad", "off-topic" and so forth. How are these types of questions supposed to be handled? Closed with "other" or answered with an explanation of why this isn't possible in the first place?

Comment: Your title appears to be cut off.

Comment: Custom close reasons can be used for these types of questions. Add a specific comment with the reason it's off topic. Alternatively, you can just leave a comment mentioning that such a thing is not possible, and often the asker deletes the question.

Answer (score 4):

We don't close questions just because the answer is "you can't do that" or "no" or otherwise negative.

If a user, for example, wants to ask "how I can I implement real-time ray-tracing on a NES using home-brew development kits?", then "you can't do that" is a perfectly acceptable, correct answer.

If the question *is* close-worthy, however, we have custom off-topic close reasons for users with sufficient reputation. Users without sufficient reputation can still flag the question.

Comment: So an answer that explains why it can't be done is the correct treatment?

Comment: And possibly a downvote for lack of research?

Comment: I'd say no. Perhaps they came here because their research didn't find anything.

Comment: This is exactly how Stackoverflow gained it's reputation. If the question is pertinent, shows evidence of research, and is finite in it's scope, then surely it's valid. Funnily enough, Josh, I once read about a dev who attempted ray-tracing on a C64. Low and behold - http://beta.slashdot.org/story/186141 - Not every question has an answer on Google though. Ergo Stackexchange.

Comment: Agreed, there is no need to down vote. Ignorance does not mean you did not research.